# Functional tests in Ruby failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am running the functional test in Ruby and they are failing.

I'm getting this as result from running `rake test:functionals`

```
  1) Failure:
test_should_create_user(UsersControllerTest) [test/functional/users_controller_t
est.rb:20]:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
<3> expected but was
<2>.

14 tests, 19 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors
Errors running test:functionals! #<#<Class:0x472b82e5>: Command failed with stat
us (1): [c:/jruby-1.6.7.2/bin/jruby.exe -I"lib;test...]>
```

I already check the log file looking for SQL errors but everything seems ok.

Any idea why is this failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you haven't changed the test file, and it was automatically generated.

In this case, because there are no SQL errors, there must have been a problem with the test and/or the controller.

Assuming there is nothing wrong with the controller, the likely problems are:

- the values of the attributes your test is sending to the controller are not valid (due to validation in your model)
- the test is not authorized to create the object (if you are using devise, you need to sign in within the test)

Otherwise, the controller might have a bug.

Comment: You were right about it, everything was generated automatically. I also had a problem in the user model with the validation. I removed the validation from the model and everything works fine, now that I know what's causing the error I'll see how can I fix it. Regards